# HTML image object on click is not working

Tags: javascript, html, image-gallery

I am trying to build a gallery that opens up a large popup image or 'modal' image when a picture is clicked.

I am trying to combine the code from these two tutorials:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_portfolio_filter.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Hovering over the image causes it to fade a little but clicking does absolutely nothing.

Here is a chunk of my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="column 1">
<div class="content">
  <img id ="myImg" src="path.png" alt="img" style="width:40%">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick() = function(){
  console.log('click')
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

Nothing is being outputted to the console, not even any error messages.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: How are you combining them? You can't use the same ID repeatedly, so the image gallery needs to use classes, not IDs.

Comment: `img.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log('click')
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `()` from the `onClick` method, so your JavaScript looks like:

```js
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  console.log('click')
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

`onClick` is an attribute of a DOM element, not a function. As such, you need to assign the anonymous function to the variable with the variable assignment syntax.

See https://jsfiddle.net/7yxf3uvp/